# Shared pointers of objects built by a Factory that can diseapear

Tags: c++, pointers, uml, factory

I have a ressource, let's say a serial port.

1. This ressource might not always be present and can change from time
   to time. (factory)
2. Only one object can access this ressources at once (mutexes)
3. This ressource is shared by different objects. (smart pointers)
4. This ressource can disepear by itself for some reasons, someone unplugged the "ressource".

I have a kind of UML design in mind that would look like this:

```
    <SingleTone>                               <Abstract>
+------------------------------+                 +-----------+              +-----+
¦         Factory              ¦   *m_pRes       ¦ Ressource ¦   <¦-------- ¦ ResA¦
+------------------------------+  <o>----------> +-----------+              +-----+
¦ Ressource* createRessource() ¦                  ^    ^
+------------------------------+                  ¦    ¦
          ^ ^                                     ¦    ¦
  <uses>  ¦ ¦      +---------+     *m_pRes        ¦    ¦
          ¦ +------¦ ObjectA ¦ < >-----------------+    ¦
          ¦        +---------+                         ¦
          ¦        +---------+      *m_pRes             ¦
          +--------¦ ObjectB ¦ < >----------------------+
                   +---------+
```

I will let the factory be in charge of the "new/delete". However, I'm facing a big problem. How to make sure that all object will no point anymore to that ressource when I will call delete from the Factory and avoid a dangling pointer? Should I also implement a kind of "property listener" and when I want to "delete" my ressource from my factory, signal all holders that it disapeard and "release" the pointer (set it to null)? This sounds pretty complicated, there might be a better way ...

Yap, I will use C++ programming ...

Answer (score 2):

One, of many, solutions to this problem could use [boost weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm).

When the resource is destroyed, object instances with weak_ptr data members would find that the resource is gone. Upon that condition, they would either not perform the logic they would have, or request a new reference from some source.

Comment: Yieah nice, new concept I've never seen and seems very well suited to my case! New material to learn, that what I was looking for! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You could add another layer of indirection and have the `Resource` object act as a proxy to a `RealResource` object. When the `RealResource` instance is deleted/changed, only the `Resource` object needs to be updated. Clients always possess a valid pointer to the `Resource` proxy, which can tell whether it's in a usable state or not.

```
+----------+           +-----------+         +--------------+      +------+
| ClientA  |< >---+----| Resource  |<o>------| RealResource |<|----| ResA |
+----------+      |    +-----------+         +--------------+      +------+
                  |    | isValid() |         | use()        |
+----------+      |    | use()     |         +--------------+
| ClientB  |< >---'    +-----------+
+----------+
```

Comment: Yes, thanks I was also thinking about putting a layer like that, the Ressource could also do the monitor stuff to manage the concurrent acces!

Answer (score 1):

You can use some kind of [event driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming), where resource destroyed/created events are emitted from the factory. All objects interested in this event would register to it. In events handlers they can get pointers to a new resource.

You can use [boost::signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals.html) for the subscriber/publisher object.